Global installation of my cli tool does not work
I am trying to publish my cli tool in npm and when I install it globally it does not add the binary command correctly.
It works if I leave the binary in the dist folder but it adds about 80mb to the package and I'm honestly not happy.
This is the package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/term-toolkit
Any ideas?
re-install, create a script to build the file in "postinstall", just use a .js file no a binary
Examples:
npm install -g term-toolkit

try to run
term-toolkit -h


zsh: command not found: term-toolkit


Do other global scripts work? Share the contents of your package.json
